# Angular2 how to balance components and services

Tags: angular

I am trying to design a profile(resume) page with many parts using angular2.
These parts are photo, contact, experiences etc.

Each part editable when double clicking a text. When any part is edit mode, two button(save&cancel) will be visible.

```
A simple demo plunk is http://plnkr.co/edit/OQgaMz?p=preview
```

So, i couldn't decide which below approach is suitable for my case.

1. Single component and single service.
2. Single service(singletion) to keep application state and multiple
   component. Sharing state between components via service.
3. Single service and multiple component(parent and childs), retriving
   data only in the service, getting by parent component and passing to child via @input, for interaction using @output. 
   Application states are distributed.
4. Multiple components and multiple services with interaction between
   components.     Each component gets own data using own service, and
   keeps own states.

Do you have any suggest?

Comment: I like 2 and 3.  But for 3 I would pass down JavaScript reference types so I wouldn't have to `emit()` changes up to the parent ProfileComponent.

Comment: I would go with 3 like in [this plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/hierarchical-dependency-injection/ts/plnkr.html) from angular.io. check `app/hero-editor.component.ts` and `app/restore-service.ts`

Answer (score 0):

to me:

1- hard to maintain - easy to start up with - fragile code - I would chose it if only the requirements are very clear and won't expand/extend.

```
-- app
---- app.component.ts (your resume component)
---- app.module.ts
---- main.ts
---- app.routing.ts
```

2- this will end up being 3 as you need a wrapper around all your components to make them visible to user and that wrapper would be your parent component
this is the best approach, easy to maintain and the service will be injectable to all components and they can communicate via that, if you want to extend your resume - let's say add education part, then you create a folder under resume and you add related components.

```
-- app
---- app.module.ts
---- app.component.ts
---- app.routing.ts
---- main.ts (bootstrap)
---- resume (feature module called resume)
------ header (sub folder)
-------- header.component.ts|html|scss
------ experience (sub folder)
-------- experience.component.ts|html|scss
------ education (sub folder)
-------- education.component.ts|html|scss
------ shared
-------- resume.service.ts (manages you resume XHR)
------ resume.module.ts
------ resume.routing.ts
```

[angular2 application structure](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#application-structure)

3. refer to number 2
4. with this case you have one service per folder in the resume module, which is too much and could be only a good option if you have implemented microservices on the backend and each sub module (education, header and etc) will be communicating with a standalone service and you don't have an api gateway to wrap them up.

[microservice- api gateway](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/?utm_source=building-microservices-inter-process-communication&utm_medium=blog)